# How to implement true @ignore in cucumber-jvm?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, maven-failsafe-plugin, cucumber-junit

Does Cucumber JVM / Cucumber JUnit support **true** ignores? Not the filtered by `"~@ignore"` tag, but an actual ignore where by marking a spec with `@ignore` (without the need to go an modify the steps to throw a temporary `PendingException` as first line) it will be reported as skipped in the xml reports and hence displayed as such by the CI server such as TeamCity's build overview/status.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(tags = {"~@ignore"})
public class FooIT {
}
```

failsafe-summary.xml

```
<failsafe-summary result="254" timeout="false">
  <completed>0</completed>
  <errors>0</errors>
  <failures>0</failures>
  <skipped>0</skipped>
  <failureMessage/>
</failsafe-summary>
```

TEST-com.foo.FooIT.xml

```
<testsuite name="com.foo.FooIT" time="0" tests="0" errors="0" skipped="0" failures="0">
```

Comment: as far as i know, no there is not, but have you tried using the tags without ignoring, but listing all the tags you want to run? you can tag each feature file and list it there. if you dont want to run it, just comment it out in the cucumber options, this way, they shouldnt be listed as skipped?